# How to decide if a phrase like this is subordinate or infinitive?

Tags: phrase-meaning, infinitives, subordinate-clauses

In this sentence:

> Ann uses gloves to grab the trash.

Is *to grab the trash* an infinitive phrase or a subordinate phrase? Or maybe both?

How to decide if *to* is a infinitive marker or a subordinator in such sentences in general?

Would there be a different meanings between these two options?

Comment: The infinitive marker *to* is a subordinator.

Comment: @snailboat Can you [prove it](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/173962/what-evidence-is-there-that-to-belongs-to-any-particular-part-of-speech), old bean? Even H&P aren't sure ;)

Comment: @Araucaria As the great Araucaria once said, "All infinitival clauses are subordinate clauses." :-)  Therefore marking a clause as infinitival marks it as subordinate.  [Sure, it's highly exceptional](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/~gpullum/grammar/infinitive_sli.pdf), so you may choose not to call it a subordinator, but as long as it makes things even a little bit simpler for us in terms of description, I'm happy with the label :-)

Comment: @snailboat I was just being mischievous ;) Sorry, couldn't help it!

Answer (score 1):

It's a subordinate clause because it is a dependent of another part of the sentence. *To grab the trash* is an Adjunct of the clause *Anne uses gloves* (it gives us extra information about why Ann used gloves).

It's an infinitival clause because it uses a plain form of the verb after the word *to*. (This isn't the preposition *to*, it's other one.) All infinitival clauses are  subordinate clauses.